# Reading .dat file using Python

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

Currently, I am trying to extract data in [OPPORTUNITY Activity Recognition Data Set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/OPPORTUNITY+Activity+Recognition#)  by using Python.

There is a download link for it because I can not add the file in Stackoverflow. The file can be opened in Matlab with complicated structure therefore I am still struggling with extracting it.

But the file that I want to extract data is S1-ADL1.dat located in 'dataset' folder in the link above.

Here is the content in the file: [File Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Motnh.png)

I am using code:

```
with open("S1-ADL1.dat") as infile:
    file_contents = infile.readlines()
print(file_contents)
```

but the terminal return nothing.

Does anyone know how to get the data please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean nothing? change your print statement to `print(111111111, file_contents)` and paste what you see

Comment: can't reproduce, your code works fine when I download the dat file

Comment: 111111111 []
@JamesLin here is what terminal return

Comment: @DerekEden Can I have your contact to view because I have tried and nothing works.

Comment: Well that means your file is empty???

Comment: @JamesLin I know that but .dat file in the like I give. It contains lots of information. If you download you can see it in Matlab.

Comment: upload the file and let me see

Comment: maybe you did something to the file? I literally downloaded the file and copy/pasted your code and it worked

Comment: @DerekEden Can you show me what your terminal return ? Thanks

Comment: @JamesLin  I have uploaded the image when opening the .dat file.

Comment: You can create a test file, type in some text, then try to use that file in your code, what what you get.

Comment: @JamesLin I have created a txt file with Hello World content and this is what I get "['Hello World']" in the terminal. With the above code.

Comment: That means your code is working, have you tried opening your .dat file in text editor and see the actual content? Is your file in binary format?

Comment: @JamesLin I have tried but it can not be opened in text editor, I think it is binary format

Comment: Well there you go, even if you open the file in binary format `open('file', 'rb')` you are still reading binary data, unless you know how to convert that binary data into something meaningful, then there is no point reading the file in python.

Answer (score 0):

either use a for loop with `readlines()` or use `read()` instead.

```
with open("S1-ADL1.dat") as infile:
    file_contents = infile.read()

print(file_contents)
```

or

```
file = open('S1-ADL1.dat', 'r') 
file_contents = file.readlines() 

for line in file_contents: 
    print(line.strip())

file.close()
```

Comment: I have tried this but it still return nothing in the terminal.

Comment: Yes, I have tried both of your options and the terminal return nothing.